# Selection of "e" from "e"

Tags: combinations

Suppose, there are  3 "e" . I want to select 2 e from these  3 e. By common sense, we can say that we can select by only one way...But I want to calculate using combination formula...

MY APPROACH:

During the selection, 2 e will always occur. So, we can calculate excluding 2 e...
          n∧C_r-2
Where, n=3 and r=2. So, the answer is 1.

Is my approach correct?

Comment: Why would you want to use the "combination formula" when it is totally inappropriate to your problem? All 'e's are identical, there is only one way - end of the story!

Comment: Yeah I also know that...But it's that I want to know how can I use it in a formula...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to number all the ways you can choose $k$ elements from a group of $n$ you have to use the binomial coefficient.

In your case the result is:
$$\binom{3}{2}=\binom{3}{3-2}=\binom{3}{1}=3$$

But since all the three elements are identical, you have just $1$ way to choose 2 of them. In fact they are undistinguishable.

Comment: How can I choose 2 e from 3 e by 3 ways?

Comment: No matter how you chose, every time it would be only "e"...So, answer should be 1, shouldn't it?

Comment: So, you have a set made of three identical elements?

Comment: Yes...All are same...